# Efficient computation and assignment of points(large set) within a large set of rectangles

Tags: performance, matlab, geometry

I have a large MxN array of coordinates and I have a large set of rectangles in a structure Rect.Now i am calculating the density of each of the rectangles buy calculating the area/no of points inside it.
In Matlab an inefficient way to handle this would be something like below

```
for ii=1:size(Rect,1)
        ind = X>Rect(ii,1) & X<Rect(ii,3) & Y>Rect(ii,2) & Y<Rect(ii,4);
        Num_of_coord(ii) = sum(ind);
end
```

Now for each of the rectangles I can get the no of points from X and Y

How can this be implemented in a fast way in Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the loop using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
ind = bsxfun(@gt, X(:), Rect(:,1).') & bsxfun(@lt, X(:), Rect(:,3).') & ...
      bsxfun(@gt, Y(:), Rect(:,2).') & bsxfun(@lt, Y(:), Rect(:,4).');
Num_of_coord = sum(ind, 1);
```

Comment: aren't function_handles slower than loop?

Comment: @Kamtal Anonymous  ones are, not the built-in ones like `@gt` in this case.

Comment: for large lists of X and Rect this method is not fast enough and also memomry allocation of bsxfun will run into problems.

Comment: @shakuni `bsxfun` is memory-hungry, yes. As for "fast enough", well, `bsxfun` is usually quite fast, but of course you can try other approaches and see if they are faster